# How to find largest coefficient in matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&6\\
7&8&3\\
0&4&7
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I want know the algorithm to find largest value in matrix .

Comment: In MATLAB, when A is an m by n matrix, you can use max(max(A)).

Comment: To make to algorithm compare the first to elements pick the largest of the 2, then compare that element with the next element and pick again the largest and continue this process until you have reached the last element. It will take you $\Theta(n)$ steps where $n$ is the number of elements of the matrix

Answer (score 1):

Generally, to make the algorithm by yourself, you need to use two loops to check all the entities of the matrix for a comparative approach.

Comment: Sir , I want to develop it c programing  , could please update me algorithm!

Comment: Actually, it would be better if you may mention in the problem that you need an algorithm in C for your purpose. Sorry, I am not familiar with C, but the algorithm's structure should be like what I explained. I also  believe that you can find the code searching on the Net.

Comment: Ya thank you very much sir

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

In C code:

```
int matrix[] = {1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 3, 0, 4, 7};
int min = matrix[0];
for(i = 1; i < sizeof(matrix); i = i+1) {
  if(matrix[i] < min)
    min = matrix[i];
}
```

If you would also like to get which element is the min:

```
int matrix[] = {1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 3, 0, 4, 7};
int min = matrix[0];
int min_row = 1;
int min column = 1;
int row_size = 3;
for(i = 1; i < sizeof(matrix); i = i+1) {
  if(matrix[i] < min) {
    min = matrix[i];
    min_row = (i/3) + 1;
    min_column = (i % 3) + 1; 
  }
}
```

Here, (min_row, min_column) is the element of the minimum value.

Comment: What if its 2dimensional array or more ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: I asked the question in wrong place , I was developing C programming